# phone gap server connection tutorial not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am following this tutorial:

- http://www.indiageeks.in/phonegap-jquery-ajax-example-jsonjavascript-object-notation-response/

but when I press the buttons the request not sent 
this is my code
and when check the console I get this

[image]

it iays thet my function " connect is not defined "

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link href="jQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>Taha king</title>


        <script charset="utf&minus;8" type="text/javascript">
            function connect(e){
                alert("mmmmmmmmmmmm");
                    var term= {button:e};
                    $.ajax({ 
                    url:'http://www.indiageeks.in/tutorials/reply.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data:term,
                    dataType:'json',
                    error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
                        alert(“no connection”);
                    },
                    timeout:60000,
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#result").html("");
                        for(var i in data){
                        $("#result").append("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");
                    }
                }
               });}
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div data-role="header">

         <h1>Your resource app</h1>

        </div>

        <div dara-role="content"> 

                       <center><b>Bikes or Cars</b></center>
        <center><input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="cars" /></center>
        <center><input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="bikes" /></center>
        <center><b>Results</b></center>
        <ul id="result"></ul>

        </div>

         <div dara-role="footer">   

            <h4>&copy; carsRent.ps</h4>

        </div> 


      <!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are errors etc?

Comment: @A.B Uncaught ReferenceError: connect is not defined

Comment: @A.B also added the error to the question

Comment: you will also be not getting alert, try removing charset attribute from script tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this:

```
charset="utf&minus;8"
```

from your script tag.
If you want utf-8 encoding there is no need for that since you are using:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

`connect()` function was not exist. You forgot to insert it. please recheck again.